# ServiceStack.Swagger captures only the first route in service

Tags: routes, servicestack, swagger

Here's an issue with ServiceStack.Swagger:

1) Download [an example](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.UseCases/tree/master/SwaggerHelloWorld) from github. 
2) Go to HelloText class (or any class that is describing requests to REST service, i.e. HelloImage or Hello - in this particular example). Add one more route for the request:

```
[Route("/hellotext/{Name}", Summary = "Hello Text Service")]
[Route("/abc/{Name}", Summary = "ABC Text Service")]
public class HelloText
{
   [ApiMember(Name = "Name", 
              Description = "Name Description", 
              ParameterType = "path", 
              DataType = "string", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

3) go to local swagger-page (localhost:yourport/swagger-ui.html) or to
    resouces page (localhost:yourport/resources) and you'll see that
    "/abc/" route is captured and "/hellotext" is not

```
/resource/abc   
/resource/helloimage    
/resource/hello
```

Is this a bug or intended behaviour?
How to use swagger-ui with multiple routes? Or do I have to copy-paste request classes and split every route on it's own class?

Comment: Seems like a bug. Are you using the latest [ServiceStack Swagger plugin](http://nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Api.Swagger/)? I have a Request DTO with two routes, no problem at all.

Comment: "Copy-paste request classes and split every route on it's own class?" => This doesn't match with Service Stack's reusability philosophy.